# What do you call overtaking after overtakers? Not necessarily a single word, a phrase will do

Tags: phrase-requests, translation

What do we call the act of overtaking a vehicle which is already being overtaken by one or more cars? You see that some other car begins overtaking, and you join this overtaker, and others may join you, creating a dangerous string of overtakers.

It's kind of "blind overtaking in a row", where you blindly hope that there will be enough time for you to finish the maneuver, since your visibility is obstructed by the overtakers ahead of you.

In Russian, we call it "обгон паровозиком" - "train-style overtaking", because several overtaking vehicles look like the carriages of a train.

I was reading [a local news report](https://www.e1.ru/news/spool/news_id-66205636.html) in which a guy joined such "overtaking train" and [killed an oncoming driver](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=piHGLheoWxg), and I became curious about the phrase used in English for this "train-style overtaking".

I don't necessarily need a single word - a phrase will do. There must be some commonly used expression for this, because this must be a common while dangerous practice. I googled for "overtaking in a queue" and "serial overtaking", but there were no relevant results.

Comment: I don’t think I’ve ever heard a word for that. I’m familiar with the concept, of course, but I don’t have a specific word for it.

Comment: I don't know of one, maybe a queue (we do like a good queue)

Comment: One phrase is [**herd mentality**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herd_mentality) or **herd behaviour** but I can't find a dictionary definition that makes a good answer.

Comment: @WeatherVane - no, I'm looking for a phrase a motorist would use for describing this situation

Comment: I don't think there is one: but perhaps in US or UK it does not happen *often enough* for a phrase to be coined.

Comment: Convoy overtaking? As said in other comments, I'm not sure it's common enough to need a phrase. Cavalcade/motorcade overtaking maybe?

Comment: I live and drive in northern Italy, where Italian drivers can do crazy stunts, but, thankfully, I have never witnessed this type of behaviour on any road, be it in the countryside, urban areas or motorway. The most you see is a sports car overtaking two cars and an articulated truck... yeah, I don't think I recall seeing anything more dangerous than that.

Comment: I agree with the other comments, this is a mentality that is not often seen in  the UK or USA (that I have experienced) or Western Europe in General (with the exception of the periferique) . Although I have been forced to pull over in Russia a few times because of a stream of traffic heading down my side of the road. It is not confined to Russia though Iran is just the same  In China it would be not considered for a special word as it is normal for people to drive on the wrong side of the road. Whilst India does not seem to have yet determined what side of the road they should drive on.

Comment: The old geezer was poking along so slowly that we overtook him *three in a row*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is there is no common phrase for this.

When it does happen, it is similarly described as 'a train of cars all passing at once.'

In my experience traveling the states I have not seen this happen when vision was obstructed. It does, however, occur on long straightaways with clear vision for some distance.